# The reason behind this Output

Tags: c, printf

I have made an test where it have appeared something like this:

```
char* trim(char* strr, char* str1) {
  char* s = strr;
  while(*str1 == 32) str1++;
  while( (*str1 != 32) && (*str1 != 0) )
        *s++ = *str1++;
  *s = 0;
  return strr;
  }

int main(void) {
  char str[20] = "???";
  char str1[20] ="    bcd  \0";

  printf("(%s)\n(%s)\n", str, trim(str, str1));
  return(0);
}
```

The question was: What the above code will print and why? I got a clue on the output and why but I would like to hear from more experienced people on the subject.

At a first glance it looks like it will print:

```
(???)
(bcd)
```

but in reality the output produced is:

```
(bcd)
(bcd)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit: removed previous answer, which @Nigel Harper was nice enough to be polite in pointing out was complete nonsense.]

The arguments to `printf` (all the arguments) are evaluated in some unspecified order before execution of `printf` itself begins. Therefore, by the time `printf` starts executing, both `str` and (importantly) `trim(str, str1)` have been evaluated.

Since the `trim(str, str1)` modifies the memory that `str` points at, by the time `printf` itself is executing, the memory pointed at by `str` will have been modified to contain the `bcd` (and obviously, the pointer returned from `trim(str, str1)` will as well).

Therefore, regardless of the order in which the two arguments are evaluated, both outputs will be `bcd`.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting into strr within the function which is str in your call.  Since it is being passed by reference, the change is reflected back into the calling function.  printf will get the evaluated copy of str (same in both arguments).

Answer (score 0):

The last argument is <s>evaluated first and</s> pushed to the stack first. But the order of evaluating the arguments is not definite.

I crated a simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *go(char *s) { *s = '0'; return s; }

int main() {
    char str[] = "xyz", str1[] = "abc";
    printf("(%s)(%s)\n", str, go(str));
    printf("(%s)(%s)\n", go(str1), str1);
}
```

Output:

```
(0yz)(0yz)
(0bc)(0bc)
```

You can analyse the assembly output with this gcc command line:

```
gcc -c -g -Wa,-a,-ad x.c >x.lst
```

If You add -O2 the order is the same, but the go() function become inlined.

Hmmm... I have learned something again! Thanks for it!

Comment: I just change the order of the arguments and the same happen

Comment: You and Jeff are right! The order of the arguments on the stack is definite. The last is pushed first. But the order of evaluating the arguments is not definite! I modify my answer!